# Can I disclose transaction id of a transaction to the customer?

Tags: transaction-hash

When I use monero-python to get transaction details for the customer's address that I've given, I get the following data.

```
{'tx_id': 'efab960da464a6701f1ea4b39ba91c420d71172f9e2ba4d6e1ca9087ad5eb0bf', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 6, 12, 40, 56), 'amount': Decimal('10.000000000000')}
```

Is it safe to show tx_id to the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely safe, and the simplest way to let him know payment has been sent.
Using a block explorer tx id will let the customer check in which block it has been included.